# How to generate a core dump in ubuntu (and where to find it)?

Tags: xubuntu, core-dump

I have a program that throws a segmentation fault like:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

but I cannot find a core dump file.

What I did:

- Run `ulimit -c unlimited`
- Run `sudo systemctl enable apport`
- Run `sudo service apport start`

There is still no core dump file, neither in the local folder, nor in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` (empty), nor in `/var/crash` (just two unrelated `.crash` files from the system).

What am I missing? And should I revert any of the above commands because they don't apply for my system?

```
> hostnamectl
     Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
               Kernel: Linux 5.11.0-27-generic
         Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Does `coredumpctl list` return anything?

Comment: Did you try to inspect syslog (`journalctl`) or try `coredumpctl list`?

Comment: `coredumpctl list` prints `No coredumps found.` With `journalctl`, what would I have to look for? I gave up after 55 MB of text.

Comment: I had the same problem, and found core dump in this directory: /var/lib/apport/coredump/

Answer (score 1):

see [Sourabh Edake](https://medium.com/@sourabhedake)'s article [Core Dumps — How to enable them?](https://medium.com/@sourabhedake/core-dumps-how-to-enable-them-73856a437711)

- `ulimit -S -c unlimited` to enable the capture of coredumps.
- Install `coredumpctl` if needed (`sudo apt install systemd-coredump`).
- Capture the next coredump, as previous ones were probably not captured.
- Then `coredumpctl list` or `coredumpctl info -1` will list or show the last coredumps respectively.